# Show up modal in navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, sharepoint-2013, bootstrap-modal

I have navbar where I want to show up modal if I clic in one item.Title

So now I show my navbar in js menupopulator like these:

```
 function completeMenu(data, target) {
var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
var sufix = "</ul>";
var items = data.d.results;
var menu = "";
for (var item in items) {
    if(items[item].Funcion != null && items[item].Funcion != ""){
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + " id='"+items[item].Funcion+"'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    else
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
```

So that I want is where items[item].Title is == SignIn show modal instead open another link... can I do that?

I try something like these:

```
for (var item in items) {
    if(items[item].Funcion != null && items[item].Funcion != ""){
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + " id='"+items[item].Funcion+"'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    else
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";

    if(items[item].Title == "SignIn"){
     menu += "<li><a href="#mymodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"></a></li>"
    }
   }

    }
```

But I don´t want to show up button, I want to show a href like my menupopulator

And then in view:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="fade modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader"></asp:Label></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Test modal</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

----------------------------Update-----------------------------

There is my change but when I change it, I get only a label saying "true"

```
 function completeMenu(data, target) {
var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
var sufix = "</ul>";
var items = data.d.results;
var menu = "";
for (item in items) {
    menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    if(items[item].Title == "SignUp"){
menu += "<button type= button class=btn btn-link data-toggle= modal  data-target=#mymodal">""
}
}

$(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you need also change this line:

```
"<button type= button class=btn btn-default data-toggle= modal  data-target=#mymodal">
```

To this one:

```
"<button type= button class=btn btn-link data-toggle= modal  data-target=#mymodal">
```

Comment: I think I need an  href like these `menu += "<li><a href="#mymodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"></a></li>"`, but my syntaxis is wrong

Comment: Bootstrap modals called by data-target, in your code :  `data-target="#mymodal"`, so you dont need to have an href, button with `btn-link` class seems like the links at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you need only to get a link, click on it you will reference to another page and immediatly open a model. You can use it using js. Handling click on the link you need to show your modal like this :

```
<button type="button" class:"btn-link js-signin-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target"#mymodal">
```

And in your js code:

```
$('.js-signin-link').on('click', function(){
     window.location.href = 'SomePageWhereYouNeedToGO.html';
});
```

Or you can get it from another side:

```
<a href="#SomePageWhereYouNeedToGO.html" class="js-signin-link"></a>
```

In js

```
$('.js-signin-link').on('click', function(){
    $('#mymodal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: I don´t want to redirect to another page, now if I clic on signIn It redirects to another page, but I want to press it and only open modal instead redirect to another view, but I don´t know how to change signIn link to modal in only this option

Comment: I want to do somethink like these [Snippet](http://www.bootply.com/98624), when my for looks "SignUp" option

Comment: If you want only to open a model do `<button type="button" class:"btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target"#mymodal">`.